# cant clean cache between scenes?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have mention a strange thing in cocos2d.

in my init of game scene and menu scene, i load a frameCache plist and a spriteSheet to the cache.

i discovered that if in my game scene dealloc method i clean cache with:

```
  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
     [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];
```

so then when i replace scene to the menu, and back to the game, he doesnt load the cache again and hence get errors that he couldnt find the required frames.

so it seems that i can load frames into cache only once in every scene, and if i remove it and back to the scene, it wouldnt load again and get error.

vise versa, if i clean the cache in my menu scene,go to game and back to menu , then the menu scene also will not load the cache and cant find my required frames.

this is interesting. is there a reason for that? or am i wrong here somewhere ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events if you change scenes from oldScene to newScene is as follows:

1. newScene: init
2. oldScene: dealloc

So if you load the sprite frames in init, and clear the caches in dealloc of the former scene, the sprite frames will be unavailable in the new scene.

Your best option is to clear the caches just before you call replaceScene with the new scene.